# "The website encountered an unexpected error" right after login in

Tags: 7

So I recently bought a very cheap host just to run a not-important website on it. but when I login to admin, it shows

> The website encountered an unexpected error, Please try again later.

message, since its a shared host I checked into my cpanel for error logs, there were just two errors regarding my `.htaccess` files (in root and also sites/default/files) regarding `FollowSymLinks` not being available here, so I commented out those lines and all error logs now are gone. but still I get the error message after I try to login.

I contacted the webmaster regarding `FollowSymLinks` and he said we are using `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` .

however with or withought FollowSymLinks I still get the error message while my error logs in cpanel is empty.

Any Ideas or hints?

Comment: well I get this error for like 2 days

Comment: is your .htaccess file readable by webserver?

Comment: yea I assume it is because of permission and also because of errors I was getting from my .htaccess before

Comment: www.yourdomain.com/user works?

Comment: yes it looks ok

Comment: can you check the last error logged in your watchdog db table

Comment: yea give me a minute

Comment: believe it or not there is no watchdog table in my db structure

Comment: did you have imported database properly?

Comment: I guess, there was no error, I imported as a tar.gz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10854/discussion-between-arpitr-and-sohail)

Comment: Thanks for the affort guys, the issue was db damage, I reupload the dump and it works fine again, arpitr please leave an answer so i can select it as the right one

Comment: I am glad it helped you, I have added an answer keeping it generic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to login then you can try checking the logged error directly looking into your database watchdog table.

In your case:As per our chat you were missing watchdog table so importing the database back helped you.